# multiple git repositories (managing by using PHP)

Tags: php, git, bitbucket, git-submodules

My project demands that I manage everything using **PHP**.

I cloned some repos from bitbucket into my server and now the directory structure looks like this:

`_root
  |_git-repo-1
  |    |_.git
  |    |_codes
  |         |_sub-folders
  |
  |_git-repo-2
  |    |_.git
  |    |_codes2
  |         |_sub-folders
  |
  |_git-repo-3
       |_.git
       |_codes3
            |_sub-folders3`

Since I am using **PHP** to manage them I am facing problems to manage them all from the *root* as the config file has customized itself while initiating the first repo.

Now my question is

> Is there a way I can keep my PHP files into the **root folder** and manage
>   the individual git repos from there? I am not using any special app or
>   module but relying upon shell_exec to manage the repos.

I am aware of **git submodule** but I am wondering if there is any better option to handle this project.

Comment: How exactly do you manage them with PHP ?

Comment: @VighIosif I am using shell_exec from PHP to run UNIX shell commands.

Comment: and what problems are you having this way? if you're using low level stuff, you should be able do anything

Comment: @VighIosif I just need to know how do I run git commands (add/commit/pull/push) for every individual repo.

Answer (score 0):

I found the best solution (at least for me) after looking for it everywhere.

When I am inside a root I can simply add few commands to go inside, do the work and then come back to the root.

For this purpose I can concatenate commands and run them from a single shell_exec command.

```
<?php

echo shell_exec('cd _git-repo-1; git add file1; git commit -m "Test Commit" file1; cd ..;');

?>
```